# itext PDF/A load OutputIntents

Tags: java, android, itext, pdfa

I would like to create a PDF/A(Archive) with Itext 5 on Android.
I get the error:

> com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAConformanceException: If an uncalibrated colour space(DeviceRGB/DeviceCMYK/DeviceGray) is used in a file, then that file shall contain a PDF/A OutputIntent.

Not sure(didn't find any other solution), but I think I  need to add output intents from file:

```
File file = new File("resources/data/sRGB_CS_profile.icm");
ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream(file));
writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);
```

But I just can't get it from project resources. Any idea how to make that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputStream ins = context.getResources().openRawResource(
                    context.getResources().getIdentifier(
                      "icc_profile", "raw", context.getPackageName()));
ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.getInstance(ins);
if (icc != null) {
    writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", 
                            "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);
}
```

And call `pdfDocument.open();` before that.